# Error with Loading Saved Keras Model in Shiny App

Tags: shiny, keras

Greeting Everyone,

I am newbie to ML...i have been learning to built model based on Keras in R and integrating with Shiny app. My test project that i am trying to built is to classify images of forms that receive for processing in my organization. CNN model I have built works fine when loading model in R Script for Prediction. However when try to load the model in Shiny app, i am getting an error

**Error: argument "filepath" is missing, with no default**

Below is the code of shiny app that i am trying built. Please help with understanding what i am doing incorrectly.

Note: I have tried to call model from within server function / outside of the as well. Both produce the same error.

```
library(shiny)
library(keras)
library(EBImage)
library(reticulate)
#pmodel <- load_model_weights_hdf5("E:\Sriram\shiny\image_classifier.h5")

ui <- fluidPage("Hello World",
fileInput(inputId = "imgfile",label = "Upload Your Image file",accept = c(".jpg",".jpeg")),
imageOutput("Page"),
"Printing Results",
textOutput("result")
)

server <- function(input,output)
{

output$Page <- renderImage({
src <- input$imgfile
src <- src$datapath
list(src = src,
height = "300",
alt = "This is alternate text")
})

output$result <-renderText({
pmodel <- load_model_weights_hdf5("E:\Sriram\shiny\image_classifier.h5")
img<-readImage(input$imgfile)
rimg <- img
rimg<-resize(rimg,100,100)
x <- array_reshape(rimg,c(1,100,100,3))
prob <- pmodel %>%
predict_proba(x)
pred <- pmodel%>%
predict_classes(x)
c<-c('HCFA','UB','Dental','Superbill-HCFA','Superbill-UB','Medicare', 'COB', 'Attach','Blank','EOB','MEOB')
paste("Image uploaded is -> %s Page with accuary of %s %%",c[pred])
})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`library(shiny)
```

Comment: Please provide the complete traceback you get when the error happens, for now we can say some argument is missing, but now where. The where is provided in the traceback.

Comment: RStudio Console displays                     
> runApp('E:/Sriram/shiny')
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7450
Warning: Error in file.info: invalid filename argument
  95: file.info
  94: session$fileUrl
  93: transform
  92: func
  90: f
  89: Reduce
  80: do
  79: hybrid_chain
  78: origRenderFunc
  77: output$Page
   1: runApp
Warning: Error in normalize_path: argument "filepath" is missing, with no default
  94: normalize_path
  93: load_model_weights_hdf5
  92: renderText [E:\Sriram\shiny/app.R#29]
  91: func
  78: origRenderFunc
  77: output$result
   1: runApp

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find solution for error. Instead of loading weights, I used load_model_hdf5 function for calling in shiny.